# Where the reference count of a component of msi installer stored?

Tags: wix, installation, windows-installer

For a shared component of more than 2 products, Windows Installer stores reference count of that shared component so that uninstalling one of those products doesn't break other products. I'd like to know how this can be done, where the reference count of a shared component is stored. How can I reset broken reference count?

Answer (score 4):

I've got some info about reference count of components from http://windows-installer-xml-wix-toolset.687559.n2.nabble.com/Windows-Installer-Service-and-reference-counting-td702967.html

> Components are referenced, but not really reference counted. Instead,
>   Windows Installer remembers each product which installed a component
>   and where it installed it to. The actual format is undocumented and
>   should not be relied upon; however, if you want to look at it, they’re
>   in the registry under
>   HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Installer\UserData\\Components.
>    is the user’s security identifier, for per-user installs; for
>   per-machine installs, it’s the well-known SID S-1-5-18 (which is Local
>   System).

Comment: Note that the component GUIDs listed under this registry key cannot be found be searching the registry for the GUID because they are reformatted. I was able to find the GUID I was looking for by reversing the first segment of my component GUID and searching for that.